# React Native Elements - Wrapping a touchable opacity around an input does not work in IOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-elements

I am having a very peculiar issue with React Native Elements Text Input along with using touchable opacity.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, View, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { Input } from 'react-native-elements';

const test = () => (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('we hit here')}>
    <Input disabled>
      {children}
    </Input>
  </TouchableOpacity>
)

export default test;
```

So the outer rim of the input field is completely clickable, however, the center of the component, it cannot be clicked.

This works perfectly for android however.

Any ideas

Answer (score 19, accepted):

if anyone has this issue, then the you need to supply a pointerEvents to 'none' for the entire component to be clickable:

```
<View pointerEvents='none'>
<Input disabled>
      {children}
    </Input>
</View>
```

Answer (score 10):

Mubeen hussain answer is correct, but to be more precise it's like this

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('we hit here')}>
  <View pointerEvents="none">
    <Input disabled>{children}</Input>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution of pointerEvents='none' works for me, i had the same problem.

But in my case, my input sometimes have a rightElement (an iconButton to remove the content selected), in this case, the pointerEvent='none' make my remove button untouchable, my partial solution was use the same condition that show my remove button, to control pointerEvent value. But the usability was bad, so when the button appears only it is touchable and the rest of the input is not, returning to the initial problem.

If anyone has any suggestions for my case, I would appreciate it.

My component example:

```
const isRemove = onRemove && viewValue

return (
    <Pressable onPress={onOpenModal}>
        <View w='100%' pointerEvents={!isRemove ? 'none' : undefined}>
            <FitTextInput
                showSoftInputOnFocus={false}
                isReadOnly={true}
                rightElement={
                    isRemove ? (
                        <FitPressable onPress={onRemove} p={1.5}>
                            <FitIconAwesome size='md' icon={faClose} />
                        </FitPressable>
                    ) : undefined
                }
            />
        </View>
    </Pressable>
);
```